# 'Answer' vs 'respond to'

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

What is the difference (if any) between:

> Next week, a computer trainer will be here to *answer* any questions you may have.

and

> Next week, (...) to *respond to* any questions (...).

Comment: There's no meaningful difference.

Comment: It depends on the nature of the response. If the response is for the trainer to stand on their head after a question is asked, then they aren't actually providing an answer …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[respond to your question,answer your question](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=respond+to+your+question%2Canswer+your+question&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crespond%20to%20your%20question%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canswer%20your%20question%3B%2Cc0)

[to respond to questions,to answer questions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+respond+to+questions%2Cto+answer+questions&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20respond%20to%20questions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20answer%20questions%3B%2Cc0)

[to respond to any question,to answer any question](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+respond+to+any+question%2Cto+answer+any+question&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20respond%20to%20any%20question%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20answer%20any%20question%3B%2Cc0)

The three ngrams shown as an introduction make it clear that "respond" is rarely used in comparison to "answer".

"Respond", in its primary sense, means rather "to reply" and not specifically "to give an answer", [OALD, 1](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/respond?q=respond); however, it is used as a synonym for "answer", albeit it is a quite formal one. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWLUe2wswpE) is another point of view that insists on this difference.

*Example (**LPH's**)*

- They'd been waiting for explanations from the office and no one responded for two weeks, but a secretary finally did; however that was to tell them no one could answer their request as there was not  any personel  in possession of sufficient knowledge to do that.